# set variable to a part of string bug

Tags: applescript

I write my code like this:

```
set this_text to choose file

set olmfilesname to name of (info for this_text)

set olmfilesname1 to ((characters 1 thru -5 of olmfilesname) as string)
```

However, when I get the result it's like this:

```
q
w
e
r
t
y
```

Can anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: If I run your _code_ in **Script Editor**, I get the expected results, that been just the _filename_ sans the _extension_ when the target _file_ has a three character_ extension_. You need to include adequate information to reproduce your issue. Please have a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Have you also been playing with AppleScript’s text item delimiters?